# Serve static files with Django without STATIC_URL

Tags: django, static-media

Hi have an application that uses STATIC_URL in the settings. For example:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

these in url patterns:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

and its usage in a html is like:

```
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}images/formshare-computer.png" width="497" height="363"/>
```

This works if the application is served in http://mydomin.org/ but if I serve it in http://mydomin.org/myapp/ I need to change the STATIC_URL

Is there a way to serve static files without STATIC_URL or how to properly use it in the html?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css) - in your templates use:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'images/formshare-computer.png' %}" width="497" height="363"/>
```

MEDIA_* settings have nothing to do with your static content, they are used to manage user-uploaded content.

Comment: That returns the same as STATIC_URL. If the Django application is running using WSGI in for example http://localhost/myapp/ then if you use /static/ does not exists.